# Is it possible to set printer to print only 1 page in CSS?

Tags: css, asp.net, printing

I have a print preview in CSS that contains many pages. Can I set the printer to automatically print the page 1?

Is there any solution to my problem

Comment: in your print css you can just say display: none, to all the elements you don't want to print.

Comment: Actually the problem is that there is an existing page that I don't know where it came from.. I review the code but still I can't find it so I decide to set the printer to print only the first page.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS Media Types

Something like this:

```
@media print {
    .class-you-want-to-hide {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many different ways to do it. Here are some:

**Solution #1 - Using CSS Media**

```
@media print {
  body * { //
    visibility: hidden; // Have everything except printsection hidden
  }
  #printsection * {
    visibility: visible; // Have printsection visible
  }
  #printsection {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

**Solution #2 - JQuery**

```
new = window.open();
new.document.write($('#printsection').html());
new.print();
new.close();
```